# Issue from my buck/boost converter

Tags: high-voltage, buck-boost, ripple, bidirectional, isolator

After my simulation, I am getting this in my output, which does not look good at all. I find it difficult to find a spice model for DC/DC isolator that can give me a positive, negative supply, and common to connect the SiC drive to.
[image]

I decided to do it this way as shown in the datasheet, and this was my output result when the input voltage was 400V.
[image]

Note: this is just for simulation purposes.
Please assist me; I need to start building my PCB for the DC/DC isolator and will be using "MEJ2D1209SC." I am unable to get a spice model for this product.

Comment: Cheat and use the e function? It will isolate whatever input signal to give output signal. Gain can be used too if you for example want to have 3.3 V input and 15 V output.

Comment: what are you displaying on the graph? what's the graph supposed to look like? And this displayed circuit diagram isn't buck-boost.

Comment: That is what I am getting for my output. I am using that gate drive to drive my SiC mosfet. My issue is that there is no dc/dc isolator, so the SiC has to be connected this way as shown in the datasheet to run my simulation.